# Object oriented programming without initializing

Tags: python, oop

I have read many similar questions but I still don't get this.

Look at this example:

```
class Cat:
    pass

a_cat = Cat
a_cat.name = "hs"
a_cat.name
'hs' #returns this
```

Above I have made an instance of the `cat class` and the `name` is about that cat specifically. No `__init __` used.

Here is a similar example but with `__init__`.

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

doggo = Dog("ad")
doggo.name
'ad' #returns this
```

Question:
If both versions allow passing methods to individual instances of each class then why bother doing the second approach? They look like the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that the init method is called on initialization of the object, eg it means you need to pass the parameters. Let's say you have a Class Dog that has a color, you cant use the Dog without the color so you need to pass a color otherwise function that depends on this color won't be able to run. 
Here is also a good link for explaining it: [https://micropyramid.com/blog/understand-self-and-**init**-method-in-python-class/](https://micropyramid.com/blog/understand-self-and-__init__-method-in-python-class/)

For the example with the Dog, let's say you have a function with

`print(self.color)`

If you don't initialize the class with the color the function won't run. The `__init__` function is always running on the initialization and you can specify parameters that must be passed for initialization from the object. To refer the dog --> the color.

Comment: Regarding the last part of your answer: The version I wrote doesn't initialize with the `name` yet it runs normally. I don't get it

Comment: After "a_cat = Cat", if you tried "print(a_cat.name)", you will get error.
For Dog, After "doggo = Dog("ad"). if you tired "print(doggo.name)", you wont get error as it is ad

Comment: During the initialization of an object the function __init__ is also executed also for the cat example (which runs  the __init__ from the parent which is the object class. In your case of the dog, you expect a value in the init function

Comment: @SanthoshKumar I tried what you said and both worked no errors from the cat at all

Comment: @user12436030 try to run this ```class Cat:
    def print_color():
       print(self.color())



c = Cat()
c.print_color()``` since you did not have an init function that sets `self.color` it will fail

Comment: My versions in the question ask a different thing.Your example is not similar to this.

Comment: that's why you should expect variables that need to be present in the __init__ method. Otherwise, you have to make sure on initialization of the object that the variables are set

Comment: yes, that's the weird part though because The first example I wrote does not contain init but still works.

Comment: because you explicit set the value `a_cat.name = "hs"`. But let us say you forget from all the times you initialize the object once to set the name. Than your program runs into errors, and you need to find the nasty bug. But if you use the __init__ from the second example you "enforce" that the object cant be initialized without the name. 
Python as language doesn't force you how to set the variables from an object but if the values are required for functions from the object you should initialize them with it.

Comment: So these two versions work the same but it helps mostly in organizing to do it with init and setting the methods that are going to be used as parameters?

Comment: Simplified: yes.

Answer (score 1):

Difference between first and second approach is that, with the help of second approach you are forcing the newly created object to have some default values before calling any of its methods.

In that way, we can avoid getting errors when calling the methods that handle properties with no value.

Answer (score 1):

Problem with the first approach is that `a_cat` has no `name` attribute unless you assign it. In pragmatic OOP (which is more paradigm rather than any specific language  implementation and definitely can be done "right" in Python too) you want objects of same class have same "protocol" - set of properties and methods - which helps a lot when writing code that uses these classes. E.g. if you have class *Vet* that uses class *Cat*, programmer of *Vet* doesn't need to inspect every instance of *Cat* to see if there's name before doing something with it because name is part of *Cat* protocol and is always there.

In Python `__init__()` is often used to make sure that all instances of your class will have all required properties right when instantiated so then when somebody in their *Vet* class does `if cat.name.startswith('A'):` they won't end up with `AttributeError` exception when `name` attribute wasn't set in that particular instance of *Cat*.

Comment: So these two versions work the same but it helps in organizing to do it with init and setting the methods that are going to be used as parameters?

Comment: Of course the end result from both approaches is same. Way with `__init__()` is more pragmatic, cleaner, predictable. Also you don't need to have all initialized attributes in `__init__()`. E.g. when you initialize your *Cat* from file, you might have only `__init__(self, file)` and its body open the file and load all arguments and so on... so it's not exactly same in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Object-oriented programming is all about *encapsulation*. When you define an object, you *encapsulate* some piece of knowledge about real world into this object.

Encapsulation is all about prohibiting manipulation of internal state of object directly from outside world. And by "manipulation of internal state" I mean direct modification of object attributes, exactly like in your example:

```
dog = Dog()
dog.name = 'Spot'
```

This is exactly the opposite of what OOP trying to achieve.

Instead, OOP establishes a well-defined pattern: you *initialize* an object with initial state when create it. So, here is where constructors comes from. And in order to initialize object when creating it, you need to pass some arguments to constructor.

This is why "constructor with arguments" approach is *always* preferred over "create, then assign attributes" approach. Even more, in ideal world, each object should be immutable after it was created with initial state, and only allow to *query* it's state and prohibit to *change* it.